# systemd mount 'rootfs' according to '/proc/cmdline'

Tags: linux, systemd, fstab, btrfs

#### SETUP

Im running Debian 8 (jessie/testing) amd64 with systemd.

On my system partition containing a btrfs filesystem, I do have the following layout:

```
/dev/sda1  
|-root  
|-root_snapshots/  
   |-snapshot#1
   |-snapshot#2
```

In order to fully boot from a snapshot, I currenty have to change the subvolume:

- in /etc/fstab
- in the grub console (edit mode)

when booting.

#### PROBLEM

The change to '/etc/fstab' requires a running system - i.e. from a flashdrive - what I want to avoid

#### SCENARIO

Assume something is really broken, and I had to boot from a snapshot#1:
I'd rather only change the subvolume in the grub console, and have the rootfs mounted on the correct subvolume (here: snapshot#1).

Without a change in /etc/fstab, systemd would still mount the rootfs from the entry specified in /etc/fstab -> yielding the wrong rootfs to be mounted

### QUESTION

- Can systemd be told to mount the rootfs from the 'rootflags=subvol=' parameter of '/proc/cmdline'
- Or is there another solution to circumvent this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be helpful. There is a list of kernel command line params which systemd understands: http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/kernel-command-line.html
There is an option fstab=, and rd.fstab

> Takes a boolean argument. Defaults to "yes". If "no", causes the generator to ignore any mounts or swaps configured in /etc/fstab. rd.fstab= is honored only by initial RAM disk (initrd) while fstab= is honored by both the main system and the initrd.

So if set in grub/grub2 (I don't know what you are using) root=/dev/required_dev fstab=no it should boot as expected.

Comment: good proposal, though I run into a kernel panic - my initrd(?) does not seem to know what to mount as rootfs (`unable to mount unknown device block(0,0)`). At least I'm sure it's ignoring my fstab === Any further hints?

Comment: So you are appending to kernel line root=/dev/reuired_dev ...fstab = no and it is failing. Several reasons can result in such a failure, you can see this  [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71332/kernel-panics-with-cannot-open-root-device-error-where-do-i-append-the-root). And I will need more info about you device schema

Comment: As you were! I just updated my system (with a foreshadowing in mind) - seems this was a bug, because now everything works as expected!! Tnx very much. === btw: would you also favor adding `fstab=no` as a standard option, and working with unit.mounts?

Comment: I could not get the question. Could you clarify?

Comment: In order to ease switching to a snapshot: I would prefer not to use /etc/fstab at all, but only the `root=` cmdline parameter. As other mounts (like /home, i.e.) become unavailable without an fstab, I'd convert them to systemd unit files (i.e. `home.mount`) === My question is, would you rather disregard this approach, and if: why?

Comment: Because as in the answer there are kernel params which systemd understands. And you do not have to change anything special. In your approach if I am honest I think it is possible, but it requires a lot of things to be redone in a custom matter that in future may break differnet things, or kind of system update will remove and you will have to put it again.